# Fake stack overflow points

Tags: discussion, reputation, flair

I often visit users profile on stackoverflow, and their website when they have one.

I came across a blog with a fake flair, stating the person has twice as much reputation and many more badges than in reality.

Should I do something about it?

Comment: "What should I do about it?" - I'd suggest you laugh at the poor delusioned sucker who feels the need to fake his fake internet points...

Comment: Stop telling folks about my fake flair minting side business. It's seeeeeeekrit!

Comment: What's the point in downvoting a discussion thread?

Comment: As the downvote button states, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or **not useful**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Isn't there a combined flair for all of your sites on the network? Are you sure they weren't using that? Even if they weren't, as everybody else said, who cares?

Comment: Is it a Stack Overflow flair, or a network wide Stack Exchange flair? I have twice as much network wide reputation than SO reputation.

Comment: Ok, I get it, nobody cares. I would, but I can't delete the question.

Comment: Something to keep in mind, the flair shows your rep network wide and the same for badges.

Comment: Point at them and laugh?

Comment: @Will Most constructive comment so far ;)

Comment: Sounds like someone [saved up their Unicoins](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227525/what-does-unicoin-reputation-to-the-max-do)

Answer (score 28):

Nothing.

This is very easy to check and really affords them nothing.

If someone checks on them, they will know. And if they don't, they don't.

[image: xkcd 386]

As [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/386/)  illustrates...

Answer (score 13):

If they're simply doctoring up their flair image, the intent *might* not be nefarious, depending on how egregiously inflated they've made it. It could just be a joke. Even if it's not, there's very little reason to care about things people put on web sites that aren't true - if the reverse were the case the Internet would implode.

Now, if you see our logo being used in a way that somehow conveys our *endorsement* of something or someone in a way that doesn't seem to jive with [our trademark guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), then we'd appreciate a [short note via email](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) letting us know about it.

[image]